# Constrain user impersonation with Google Service Account

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

My goal is to have a program on our servers update numerous Google Sheets, from time to time, over months.

The only I could find to do this within the current iteration of the Google API was to set up two-legged OAuth, with a Google Service Account. This Service Account can impersonate any user. I just have it impersonate a bot user (e.g. sheetsbot2000@sample.com) for now.

Is there a way to do this without giving the Service Account the ability to impersonate any user? Could I constrain it to just be sheetsbot2000@sample.com?

Comment: It seems no constraint has been mentioned in [Creating a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount). Not sure if it fits your usecase but you can use [Appscript Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to do some task for you from time to time depending on the time you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Who owns those sheets? If it is owned by a few accounts that you have, You could manually generate a OAuth refresh token and store it with the "server program". It can use these refresh tokens to get an access token and then manipulate the sheet.
If the sheets owned by other people, you can still do the same but you'll have to get OAuth permission from them and store a refresh token.